# Can't open port with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to open IMAP ports 993 and 143 with iptables. I've thought of rules like this:

`-A INPUT -p TCP --dport 993 -j ACCEPT`

I've ran the command, added to the chain. `iptables -L -v` returns:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1358 packets, 105K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
40587 4761K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
   96  5199 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
   11   580 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
    4   176 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
    2    88 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8888

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1205 packets, 2969K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
39398 4668K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Then I'm in panic as there isn't a way to save the rules. Or I don't know if pressing enter saved them but `iptables save` is not a recognized command, `iptables --help` doesn't say anything about applying rules. I'm also not sure, that `iptables -L`'s output means that the rule is active till the restart or if it's yet to be activated somehow.

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-02-14 11:51 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000013s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
7777/tcp open  cbt
9200/tcp open  wap-wsp
```

I've opened an online port scanner web service, which also returned the same result.

This is iptables v1.4.2 and an ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Is someone actually *listening* on tcp/993 on this host ?

Comment: Good catch. It was a dovecot config error, that didn't let it start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Saving IPTables in Ubuntu**

From [the ubuntu iptables documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

> sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"

Don't Panic.